# Why does exporting data to CSV give only numbers?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to export a mongo strucuture to CSV with the following code:

```
file = Tempfile.new(['genreport','.csv'],file_path)
file_name = file.path()
CSV.open(file_name,"w") do |csv|
result_cursor.each do |eachdoc|
    eachdoc.each do |key,value|
        csv<<key.to_s
        csv<<value.to_s
    end
    csv<<"\n"
end
end
```

The CSV file is created as expected, but it is full of numbers only. What am I doing wrong?

Here are the types:

`result_cursor` is a mongo cursor, `eachdoc` will be a hash, and `key` and `value` will be a String.

Comment: Your sample code is missing the definition of `file_path`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your code differs or alters the context of whats posted, but when I try to run the code as is, I get an exception (undefined method `map' for 'value of key'). However, when I do this, it works fine.

```
file = Tempfile.new(['genreport','.csv'],file_path)
file_name = file.path()
CSV.open(file_name,"w") do |csv|
  result_cursor.each do |eachdoc|
    eachdoc.each do |key,value|
      csv << [key, value]
    end
  end
end
```

That really doesn't help explain the numbers you're seeing though. Perhaps something else is overriding the contents of the temp file.